# Prove that $\frac{1}{2}N_1(A_1,A_2)\leq N_2(A_1,A_2) \leq N_1(A_1,A_2)$ where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two norms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-norms

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ two bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $E$.

> I want to prove that
> $$\frac{1}{2}N_1(A_1,A_2)\leq N_2(A_1,A_2) \leq N_1(A_1,A_2),$$
> where
> $$N_1(A_1,A_2)=\displaystyle\sup\left\{\|A_1 x\|^2+\|A_2 x\|^2;\;x,y\in E,\;\|x\|=1\right\},$$
> and
> $$N_2(A_1,A_2)=\displaystyle\sup\left\{|\langle A_1 x, y \rangle|^2+|\langle A_2 x, y \rangle|^2;\;x,y\in E,\;\|x\|=\|y\|=1\right\}.$$

I think that the inequality $N_2(A_1,A_2) \leq N_1(A_1,A_2)$ follows by applying the C.S. inequality. But I cannot prove the first inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\|x\|= 1$ and $y_1=\displaystyle {A_1x\over \|A_1x\|},$  $\displaystyle y_2={A_2x\over \|A_2x\|},$ we have
$$|\langle A_1x,y_1\rangle |^2=\|A_1x\|^2\qquad |\langle A_2x,y_2\rangle |^2=\|A_2x\|^2$$
(if $A_jx=0$ we set $y_j=x$). Thus
we get
$$N_2(A_1,A_2)\ge |\langle A_1x,y_1\rangle |^2+|\langle A_2x,y_1\rangle |^2\ge \|A_1x\|^2$$
$$N_2(A_1,A_2)\ge |\langle A_1x,y_2\rangle |^2+|\langle A_2x,y_2\rangle |^2\ge \|A_2x\|^2$$

Hence
$$N_2(A_1,A_2)\ge {1\over 2}[\|A_1x\|^2+\|A_2x\|^2]$$
and
$$N_2(A_1,A_2)\ge {1\over 2}\sup_{\|x\|=1}[\|A_1x\|^2+\|A_2x\|^2]= {1\over 2}N_1(A_1,A_2).$$

The inequalities are sharp. It can be seen already in two dimensions. Let
$$A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad A_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $$N_1(A_1,A_2)= 2,\qquad N_2(A_1,A_2)=1$$
The first equality is attained at $x=(1,0).$ Concerning the second one observe that for $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ we get
$$\displaylines{|\langle A_1x,y\rangle |^2+|\langle A_2x,y\rangle |^2\\ =|x_1|^2|y_1|^2+|x_1|^2|y_2|^2 \le 1}$$ if $\|x\|=\|y\|=1.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't see why $$N_2(A_1,A_2)\ge {1\over 2}[\|A_1x\|^2+\|A_2x\|^2]$$?

Comment: The first term after "Therefore" is less than or equal to  $N_2(A_1,A_2).$

Comment: @Student I have re-edited the answer. Should be easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer

Comment: I see in a paper that these inequalities are sharp. Do you know Professor two operators $A_1$ and $A_2$ which realized the equality? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Student Please address me Ryszard. The equality $N_1=N_2$ is attained when $A_2=0$ or $A_1=A_2.$

Comment: Yes Professor. The problem is the first inequality

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help Ryszard